# sounddevice record "out" parameter

Tags: python, python-sounddevice

I would like to use the "out" parameter to write a recorded signal to a given numpy array but I don't get any audio appended to the array I am passing it. Should a samplerate be defined if I want it to use the default samplerate? There is no specific example usage in the documentation so if there any suggestions about proper usage please see the example below:

```
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np
import time

input_chs = [1,2]
rec_array = np.zeros([1, len(input_chs)])
sd.rec(out=rec_array, mapping=input_chs)
time.sleep(1)
sd.stop()
print(rec_array)  # Returns original rec_array
```

I also tried

```
rec_array = sd.rec(out=rec_array, mapping=input_chs)
```

but the results were the same.

Answer (score 2):

The recorded audio data is not *appended* to the `out` array. The `out` array is filled with the recorded data, up to its size, then the recording stops (assuming that you use `sd.wait()` or `blocking=True`).

You are passing an `out` array with only one row, that means that only one frame will be recorded. You should use `int(desired_duration_in_seconds * samplerate)` rows for your `out` array.

In other words, you must know beforehand how long the recording is supposed to be.
Then you can use `sd.wait()` for the recording to be finished.

If you want to make a recording where you don't know the duration beforehand, you should have a look at the example https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/blob/master/examples/rec_unlimited.py.

> Should a samplerate be defined if I want it to use the default samplerate?

If you want to use the default, you don't have to explicitly specify it.

Comment: I appreciate the quick and thorough reply, that functionality makes more sense. Thank you for making this useful tool!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad if I could help! If an answer is helpful to you, you should consider up-voting (by clicking the up array) and/or "accepting" the answer (by clicking the check mark). This is the way of saying "thank you" on stackoverflow!